# How does current stay the same after being subtracted by an opposing current in a subloop?

Tags: current, mesh-analysis

In a course *Linear Circuits 1: DC Analysis*, the practice problems on mesh analysis made me think about the nature of current.

Suppose in the diagram attached below Is1 = 10 A and Is2 = 5 A. So the current through R1 (from the perspective of loop I1) will be I(R1) = I1-I2 = 5 A. So the current from Is2 in subloop I2 on branch "b" is 5 A, on the resistor branch "e" it is subtracted by the 10 A (so the momentum is gone). But on branch "a" the  current is still supposed to be 5 A.

The same applies to subloop I1: the surrent on branch "d" is 10 A, in branch "e" 5 A of it is subtracted by the current I2 from Is2 (so the momentum is gone); but on branch "c" it is still supposed to be 10 A.

How can current regain it's initial momentum after being subtracted?

[image]

Comment: it is not subtracted ... it is branched (split)

Comment: To find the current through the resistor R1 in such configuration you need to subtract the current of one current source from another, because the "e" branch is shared between 2 subloops.

Comment: its a comment to your question ... `How can current regain it's initial momentum after being subtracted?` ... the current is not subtracted ... it splits into two paths, then rejoins ... the subtraction is only in your head ... currents do not subtract

Answer (score 1):

An underlying assumption of mesh analysis is that the solutions of the individual loops are valid *simultaneously*, not necessarily in isolation from each other.  If you were to look at R1, you would see that you have 5A of current flowing "down" in your picture, **not** 10A flowing "down" and 5A flowing "up".  As @jsotola said, the current flowing "right" along wire D branches into wire A and resistor E, then they combine again into wire C and return to the 10A current source.

As for the "momentum" of the current, current has no momentum*, voltage difference is what moves current.  The 5A in loop 1 that was cancelled out by loop 2 doesn't need to "regain momentum" to flow back to the 10A current source.

*Inductance can, in certain instances, be conceptualized as an effect analogous to momentum, but it is not applicable here.

Comment: if true "the current flowing "right" along wire D branches into wire A and resistor E" and assuming current sources are essentially voltage sources with known current, then charges from Is1 which branch into wire A should end on an opposite pole of Is2. And this should quickly deplete Is1.

Comment: The charges that enter a current source don't disappear (conservation of charge) or "deplete" the current source.

Comment: yes, current has no momentum. But coulombs of elementary charge are still considered as particles with elementary mass so should have something similar to momentum, especially given tons of idiotic analogies of a liquid flowing through a tubing.

Comment: Or do you mean that there will be an additional current from Is2 flowing through Is1, and on Is2 from Is1? Or that part of the charges emited from a "+" pole of Is1 will end on the "-" pole of Is2?

Comment: Positive current convention aside, in your example, half of the current that leaves IS1 will go through IS2 in the direction of its arrow ("positive" current).

Comment: "Inductance can, in certain instances, be conceptualized as an effect analogous to momentum" - can you provide more related keywords/topics for further google search

Comment: @Asetofchara There actually isn't a macro model at the level of human experience that is analogous to conduction band electrons. Some really smart people tried hard for a long time to find one. Doesn't exist. One serious problem is that nature insists on balanced charges because the electric force is \$2.4 \cdot 10^{43}\times\$ as large as gravitational forces. Almost no imbalance is tolerated in nature. So a current can leave a resistor but this current ***must*** be matched by an ***exactly*** equal current entering that resistor. And there is nothing at our level that works to this extreme.

Comment: @Asetofchara If you are interested in the details, I'd recommend a book -- *Matter & Interactions* by Chabay and Sherwood. They carefully discuss how static charges self-arrange along the surface of copper wire so that current moves. Even to the point of showing you how they must self-arrange slightly differently around a bent wire or a fork in a wire in order to ensure that currents travel in the directions they must. There is the Drude model, which is a simpler 'gas model' of electrons that is worth learning about, as well.

Comment: There seems to be a type of logical inconsistency, strange enough in such a field. Application of a form of Heisenberg's uncertainty principle necessitates in electrons being delocalized in conductors, which gives precisely controlled energy i.e. momentum. And electron mass of  9.1093837015(28)×10^31 kg also implies a momentum. These are essentially the same electrons as generated in voltage/current sources. However when focusing on electrons in a current from the source, these electrons somehow do not have a momentum, so current also doesn't.

Comment: How is it that electrons in conductors can have a momentum to apply the uncertainty principle, and electrons in voltage/current source don't?

Answer (score 0):

You have an intuitive misconception. There's no "momentum" involved. All you know about the circuit is amps and resistors - Ohm's law. The current through R1 is the sum of the two current sources: Is1 + Is2. 10 amps + -5 amps. What's happening is Is1 sources 10 ampsand Is2 takes 5 of them. The difference flows through R1.